# How to decide best number of clusters for kamila clustering with R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, mixed-type

I have a mixed type data set, so I wanted to try `kamila` clustering. It is easy to apply it, but I would like a plot to decide the number of clusters similar to knee-plot.

```
data <- read.csv("binarymat.csv",header=FALSE,sep=";")
conInd <- c(9)
conVars <- data[,conInd]
conVars <- data.frame(scale(conVars))
catVarsFac <- data[,c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)]
catVarsFac[] <- lapply(catVarsFac, factor)
catVarsDum <- dummyCodeFactorDf(catVarsFac)
kamRes <- kamila(conVars, catVarsFac, numClust=5, numInit=10,
            calcNumClust = "ps",numPredStrCvRun = 10, predStrThresh = 0.5)
summary(kamRes)
```

It says that the best number of clusters is 5. How does it decide that and can I see a plot indicating this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `kamila` package documentation

> Setting calcNumClust to ’ps’ uses the prediction strength method of
>   Tibshirani & Walther (J. of Comp. and Graphical Stats. 14(3), 2005).
>   There is no perfect method for estimating the number of clusters; PS
>   tends to give a smaller number than, say, BIC based methods for large
>   sample sizes.

In the case, you are using it, you have specified *only one* value to `numClust`. So, it doesn't look like you are actually selecting the number of clusters - you have already picked one.

To select the number of clusters, you have to specify the range you are interested in, for example, `numClust = 2 : 7` and also the method for selecting the number of clusters.

If you also want to select the number of clusters, something like the following might work.

```
kamRes <- kamila(conVars, catVarsFac, numClust = 2 : 7, numInit = 10, 
          calcNumClust = "ps", numPredStrCvRun = 10, predStrThresh = 0.5)
```

Information on the selection of the number of clusters is now present in 
`kamRes$nClust`, and `plot(2:7, kamRes$nClust$psValues)` could be what you are after.

Comment: Thank you very much Suren. I am trying the code you provided but it gives this error. _"Error in kamila(conVar = conVar[testInd, ], catFactor = catFactor[testInd,  : Input datasets must be dataframes"_

Comment: The error says `Input datasets must be dataframes`... Since I do not know what data you are using, it is difficult say exactly what happens.

Comment: Looking at your code `catVarsFac` coud be a list since you are gerring it from an `lapply`.

Comment: Thank you I am trying to fix the problem.

Comment: I am using a dataset contains 8 binary variables and just one continuous variable. So as you see in the code conVars is scaled and it is data frame. I also make catVarsFac a data frame with `catVarsFac[] <- data.frame(lapply(catVarsFac, factor))` and it still gives the same error. I could not fix it. You know what when I write just `kamRes <- kamila(conVars, catVarsFac, numClust=5,numInit=10)` it is working.

Comment: What you are doing doesn't make sense. Try this `catVarsFac <- sapply(catVarsFac, factor); catVarsFac <- as.data.frame(catVarsFac)`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, read this on [how to produce a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).